# Editor button for astyle-like code formatting?

Tags: feature-request, edits, code-formatting

There are tons of questions where code formatting is absolutely awful and unreadable (to say the least).

When I have time to do it (and when my mood is good enough, let's admit it) I run the code through [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) to make it cleaner. However I don't always do it because of the (copy / paste in local editor / save / run through astyle / reload / copy / paste in web editor) burden.

I feel that if we had in the editor toolbar a "*cleanup code formatting*" button that behaves more or less like astyle on the selected text (with reasonable settings, no need to make it 100% perfect), many people including myself would be more inclined to cleanup bad code formatting whenever they see it.

I realize that code formatting standards differ from language to language (and even *within* a specific language) but surely there's a way to find a common ground, if only indentation (which is the worst when it is missing, the rest doesn't really matter *that* much).

What do you people think about that?

Comment: This sounds dangerous. Since questions contain (by definition) something that isn't working, isn't there a potential that auto-formatting will gloss over and/or correct the issue, causing confusion?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: well I've never seen astyle change the meaning of a program. The only cases I can see would be in Whitespace (who uses that?) and perhaps in Python too. I have to admit, I see it more from a "C-family" languages point of view (C, C++, C#, Javascript, PHP, Perl, ...) but you may have a point. I'm not expert enough on those languages where whitespace matters to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Anyway it wouldn't be a requirement, just an option for the users/editors. When I run code through astyle "manually" the issue stays the same, I'm just proposing a button that lets us do it directly on SO rather than having to jump through hoops (local editor). Nobody would be forced to click on that button.

Comment: Python would throw a hissyfit over this ;-)